# How to Update/Refresh Scrolling Texts in html (as they are scrolling)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django

I'm working with Django, and I'm trying to create a horizontally scrolling text that is updated every few seconds. The code I got so far is (including some I gathered from other posts):

```
index.html

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); // This part addresses an IE bug.  without it, IE will only load the first number and will never refresh
  var my_refresh = setInterval(function() {
    $('#updateBox').load("{% url 'updateBox' %}");
  }, 1000); 
});

</script>

....
....

<div id="updateBox">
   {% include "updateBox.html" %}
</div>
```

---

```
updateBox.html

<marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left">
      {{updateText_1}}  ;  {{updateText_2}}  ;  {{updateText_3}}
</marquee>
```

---

```
views.py

def getNewTexts(parms):
    (updateText_1,updateText_2,updateText_3) = someAPIwrapper.(parms)
    return (updateText_1,updateText_2,updateText_3)

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html' )

def updateBox(request):
    (updateText_1,updateText_2,updateText_3) = getNewTexts(parms)
    return render(request, 'updateBox.html',    {'updateText_1': updateText_1, 'updateText_2':updateText_2,'updateText_3':updateText_3})
```

---

Now these codes so far results in this: The texts get correct values upon loading index page, starts scrolling, but right after it starts scrolling for 1 second (1000ms as specified in the script), the whole division "updateBox" gets refreshed and reloaded, and the texts starts scrolling from the very right-hand-side again. The result is that, only half of `{{updateText_1}}` ever gets shown.

Ideally, I would want to find a solution to only update the texts `{{updateText_1}} ; {{updateText_2}} ; {{updateText_3}}` without interupting the flow of the scrolling. Or if there are other elegant ways of achieving similar effects, I would also like to learn about them. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with `jQuery.load()` you replace the complete innerHTML of a DOM element. In your case you replace the existing `<marquee>` with a new one. But you actually want to replace the innerHTML of the `<marquee>`.

Put the `<marquee>` in your **index.html**

```
<div id="updateBox">
    <marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left">
        {% include "updateBox.html" %}
    </marquee>
</div>
```

and remove it from your **updateBox.html**

```
{{updateText_1}}  ;  {{updateText_2}}  ;  {{updateText_3}}
```

In your JS, load the ajax result into the marquee `$('#updateBox>marquee')` instead of the wrapping div:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); // This part addresses an IE bug.  without it, IE will only load the first number and will never refresh
  var my_refresh = setInterval(function() {
    $('#updateBox>marquee').load("{% url 'updateBox' %}");
  }, 1000); 
});
</script>
```